How to add the full file path in a costum header in .htaccess
On my website I have a subfolder for downloads, which I have given its own header and footer using htaccess. Now I want to display the file path in the header.

Please state exactly how you have "given its own header and footer using htaccess". Please include your existing .htaccess file in your question. "display the file path in the header" - please give an example of the expected response. "full file path" - Do you really mean the "file path" (on the server), or client-side URL-path?

You can use .htaccess to set an environment variable for the current file path and pass it to your header file. Here's how:
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Set the file path as an environment variable
RewriteRule ^downloads/(.*)$ - [E=FILE_PATH:/downloads/$1]

# Include the custom header and footer for the downloads folder
<Directory "/path/to/your/website/downloads">
    Header set My-File-Path "%{FILE_PATH}e"
    Header set X-Custom-Header "Downloads Section"
</Directory>

In the header file for your downloads folder, retrieve the FILE_PATH environment variable and display it. Here's an example:
<?php
// Get the file path from the environment variable
$filePath = getenv('FILE_PATH');

// Display the file path in the header
echo "<header>";
echo "<h1>Downloads Section</h1>";
if ($filePath) {
    echo "<p>Current File: " . htmlspecialchars($filePath) . "</p>";
}
echo "</header>";
?>

Upload your .htaccess file to the downloads folder.
Ensure your server has the necessary permissions and modules enabled (mod_rewrite and mod_headers).
Open a file in the downloads folder, and you should see the file path displayed in the header.

Notes:
Replace /path/to/your/website/downloads with the absolute path to your downloads folder.
Use the htmlspecialchars() function to sanitize the file path for security.

Let me know if you face any issues!

I did it as you described but I get an error 500 Here is the htaccess file in the root folder https://pastebin.com/uKPKSuXF

@FlorianG. Because you can't use a <Directory> container in .htaccess.

"Upload your .htaccess file to the downloads folder." - Yes, but in that case your RewriteRule will never match. You need to remove downloads/ from the RewriteRule pattern.
